# The piechart data set is merging or not picking up the Data assigned

Tags: ios, swift, pie-chart, ios-charts

I'm trying to produce a pie chart in `iOS` and there seems some issue regarding the datasets and visuals which I am not able to figure out.
This my code below:

```
let months = ["Jan" , "Feb", "Mar" , "April"]
let unitsSold = [1000.0 , 200.0, 200.0 , 200.0]

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: Double(i))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    print(dataEntries)
    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Loans")
    let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChart.data = pieChartData
    pieChart.holeRadiusPercent = 0.0
    pieChart.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0.0
    pieChart.holeColor = UIColor.clear
    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for j in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }
    pieChartDataSet.selectionShift = 0.0
    pieChartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
    pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 8.0
    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
    pieChart.legend.enabled = false
}
```

This is the output of the code, I don't understand what's happening. Either it's merging datasets or skipping something.

[image: []

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your code. 
To fix it you need change string

```
let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: Double(i))
```

to

```
let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
```

In **y** parameter you set the actual value of the entry (sold units in your case).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! @AlexSmet